# c++ pigpio i2c function question

Tags: pigpio

I have a several questions regarding pigpio I2C functions as below.

1. how to check if a I2C device is connected with pigpio? I would like to just check if a device is connected without read/write operation. i could implement the same feature with following code in Arduino. when error == 0, a device is connected.

```
Wire.beginTransmission(address);

error = Wire.endTransmission();
```

2. does "i2cZip" function support "repeated start"? there is no "start", "stop" command codes exist. bit-banged "bbI2CZip" supports "repeated start" but i need H/W function.

```
[i2cZip Example]

Set address 0x53, write 0x32, read 6 bytes

Set address 0x1E, write 0x03, read 6 bytes

Set address 0x68, write 0x1B, read 8 bytes

End

0x04 0x53   0x07 0x01 0x32   0x06 0x06

0x04 0x1E   0x07 0x01 0x03   0x06 0x06

0x04 0x68   0x07 0x01 0x1B   0x06 0x08

0x00
```

Comment: the two questions cannot be answered with one answer ... please post them separately ... this site is not a forum

Comment: Sorry. this is my first post in this site. i would post separately next time.

Comment: no, not next time ... please remove one of the questions and create a new post for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to check if  a particular  device  is connected to the I2C bus is to send  it a legal command and check the expected result.

[i2cZip](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#i2cZip)  uses  the underlying Linux I2C/SMBus driver.  I do not know if the current driver properly supports repeated  starts.

The bit bang [bbI2CZip](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#bbI2CZip) does support  repeated starts.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for making such a nice library joan. I would test  if a i2c device is connected by sending byte array of [start][address][stop]. i hope this a legal command. for the second issue, i don't have much knowledge of linux i2c driver. It seems raspberrypi linux kernel supports repeated start but i am not sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35078131/why-repeated-start-based-i2c-operation-are-not-supported-in-linux

Comment: If  you look at man page for  i2cdetect you will see that there is no general safe way  to probe for a device.  Of course if  you are sure  that a particular  device will  be present  or  no device will be present you can  tailor the query for that device.

Comment: i agree. i better find a device specific way. thanks.